# Como hacer una cadena de elementos <p></p> que se mueva infinitamente a la izquierda

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tal como puse en el titulo, alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo? un ejemplo seria asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo html que he hecho es el siguiente:

```
<div id="cadenaEtiquetas">
 <p>Texto1</p>
 <p>Texto2</p>
 <p>Texto3</p>
 <p>Texto4</p>
 <p>Texto5</p>
 <p>Texto6</p>
 <p>Texto7</p>
 <p>Texto8</p>
 <p>Texto9</p>
 <p>Texto10</p>
 <p>Texto11</p>
 <p>Texto12</p>
 <p>Texto13</p>
 <p>Texto14</p>
 <p>Texto15</p>
 <p>Texto16</p>
</div>
```

como propiedad css puse:

```
#cadenaEtiquetas p:nth-child(1){
margin-left:100%;
}

#cadenaEtiquetas p:{
margin-right:15px;
}

#cadenaEtiquetas{
width:1000px;
height:30px;
display:flex
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Y el codigo Jquery es:

```
$('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').animate({
    'margin-left':'-110%'
},30000);

var margen = $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').css('margin-left');

if(margen === '-110%'){
    $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').insertAfter('#cadenaEtiquetas p:last');
}
```

Lo que trato de hacer con el codigo es que cuando el primer

tenga -110% de margin-left, el primer

se coloque al final y asi sucesivamente, creando un movimiento infinito.

Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

```js
    $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').animate({
  'margin-left':'-110%'
 },30000);

 var margen = $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').css('margin-left');

 if(margen === '-110%'){
  $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').insertAfter('#cadenaEtiquetas p:last');
 }
```

```css
    #cadenaEtiquetas p:nth-child(1){
    margin-left:100%;
    }

    #cadenaEtiquetas p:{
    margin-right:15px;
    }

    #cadenaEtiquetas{
    width:1000px;
    height:30px;
    display:flex
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cadenaEtiquetas">
  <p>Texto1</p>
  <p>Texto2</p>
  <p>Texto3</p>
  <p>Texto4</p>
  <p>Texto5</p>
  <p>Texto6</p>
  <p>Texto7</p>
  <p>Texto8</p>
  <p>Texto9</p>
  <p>Texto10</p>
  <p>Texto11</p>
  <p>Texto12</p>
  <p>Texto13</p>
  <p>Texto14</p>
  <p>Texto15</p>
  <p>Texto16</p>
</div>
```

Comment: no queda muy claro lo que intentas hacer

Comment: Mover esos textos de derecha a izquierda infinitamente, mira el codigo, talvz ahi puedas comprender mejor

Comment: que hiciste??? Lo que necesito hacer es que esos textos se muevan, como un slider.. pero no con pausas, sino continuo.. si puedes copia los codigos en tu PC y haz la prueba, funciona, pero quiero que sea infinito

Comment: Exacto, asi es como funciona, pero ahora como harias para que ese movimiento sea infinito, es decir, que el texto1 se coloque detras del texto16 y asi sucesivamente, cada vez que el uno de los textos llega al inicio del div, automaticamente se coloque detras del ultimo, generando un movimiento infinito.

Answer (score 0):

El truco está en la propiedad `display:inline-block;` que debes aplicar en el elemento `p`:

```js
$('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').animate({
  'margin-left':'-110%'
 },30000);

 var margen = $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').css('margin-left');

 while (margen == '-110%'){
  $('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').insertAfter('#cadenaEtiquetas p:last');
 }
```

```css
#cadenaEtiquetas p:nth-child(1){
    margin-left:100%;
}
#cadenaEtiquetas p{
    width:auto;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:15px;
    height:30px;
}

#cadenaEtiquetas{
    display:flex;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cadenaEtiquetas">
  <p>Texto1</p>
  <p>Texto2</p>
  <p>Texto3</p>
  <p>Texto4</p>
  <p>Texto5</p>
  <p>Texto6</p>
  <p>Texto7</p>
  <p>Texto8</p>
  <p>Texto9</p>
  <p>Texto10</p>
  <p>Texto11</p>
  <p>Texto12</p>
  <p>Texto13</p>
  <p>Texto14</p>
  <p>Texto15</p>
  <p>Texto16</p>
</div>
```